# Why is an "unsigned int" NOT different from an EOF - can it store negative values?

Tags: c

I am trying to read a bitmap file, byte by byte, and I have a loop that runs until EOF is reached. To make that, I have a variable declared as `unsigned int` that stores each byte. The loop stops when this variable is equal to `EOF`.

The interesting point is: if I declare my variable as `unsigned int` it works. However, if I declare my variable as `unsigned short int`, the loop runs forever, because it never finds the `EOF`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    unsigned int currentByte;

    file = fopen("/home/stanley/Desktop/x.bmp", "rb");

    while ((currentByte = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        printf("%d \n", currentByte);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above is the code I am writing. If the file has a size of 90B, 90 bytes are printed on the screen.

However, for some reason, when I change it to `unsigned short int currentByte`, the loop keeps running forever. It is as if `currentByte` was never equal to `EOF`.

I read somewhere that `EOF` contains a negative value (-1). But if `EOF` is negative, why does it work when I use only `unsigned int` and why does it bug when I use `unsigned short int`? In theory, shouldn't the problem be related to the `unsigned` itself rather than the `short`? It's unsigned who can't store negative values.

I'm sorry if this is a very silly question. I'm trying to understand better how bits and bytes work, and some concepts might be strange to me yet.

I'm compiling it on the following environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 x64
- GCC: gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of `int` is greater than the size of `short`, then you will encounter this problem.

Let's assume that `EOF` is of type `int` and contains the value -1. For the sake of example, let's also assume that `int` is a 32-bit value, while `short` is a 16-bit value.

In this case, if `fgetc` returns `EOF`, it will have a value of 0xFFFFFFFF when taken as an `unsigned int`. When comparing it to `EOF` (type `int`), the signed integer -1 will be converted to the unsigned value 0xFFFFFFFF. These two values are equal, so the comparison works as expected.

However, an `EOF` returned by `fgetc`, taken as an `unsigned short`, will have a value of 0xFFFF. Because the size of `unsigned short` is smaller than the size of int, when comparing this value to `EOF`, the `unsigned short` 0xFFFF will be converted to an `int` with a value of 0x0000FFFF (extra digits shown for clarity). Since -1 is not equal to 0xFFFF for a 32-bit value, this comparison is always not equal, and the loop will not stop.

The fact that `fgetc` returns `int` hints that you should keep it as that type, as you'll otherwise discard some information or cause confusion in comparisons.

Comment: One important detail is that `unsigned short` will be promoted to `int` when compared to `EOF`. But due to unsignedness is will be zero-extended and become `0x0000FFFF`. A `signed short` would work again as it would be sign-extended and become `0xFFFFFFFF`

Comment: Your answer does not mention the "usual arithmetic conversions". With unsigned short smaller than `int` it will be converted to `int` and 0xFFFF != -1

Comment: So from what I understood, the first thing that happens is: int variables accept both negative and positive values. To work with two's complement, it reserves its first bit to indicate which signal the number has (positive or negative). 

Once `fgetc()` returns `-1` (which would be `11111111` in an **8-bit** number) and it gets converted to an unsigned, it becomes `255`. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Considering the understanding on the last comment is correct, so the problem exists when I need to store that `255` into a `short` variable (supposing it has only **4 bits**). I can't store `255` into that, but `15` at most. So, in this case, I'd have in my loop condition a `15 != 255`, which is always true. As pointed out by this and the other answers. If both understandings are correct, then I definitely think I finally got it! =)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the type `int` to match what `fgetc` returns, not `unsigned int`. The reason the loop stop condition works with `unsigned int` is not that the value is ever negative, but that, when the `!=` operator is used with `unsigned` and `signed` operands of the same rank, both get promoted to `unsigned` before the comparison. Assigning the `EOF` result of `fgetc` to `currentByte` and promoting `EOF` to `unsigned` both produce the same result, and thus they compare equal.

Comment: Thank you! I'd never have imagined that a comparison between `unsigned` and `signed` would result on both being converted to `unsigned`. Where can I find such type of information so I can learn more details about C?

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a signed integer to an unsigned integer (which happens when `EOF` is assigned to an unsigned integer variable), the result is converted to an unsigned integer by adding `UINT_MAX + 1`. So if `EOF` is `-1`, this value becomes `UINT_MAX`.

And `UINT_MAX` can properly fit only into `unsigned int` and not `unsigned short`. 
And the result of this particular conversion is implementation defined and so the behavior of the program will depend on it.

Note the `fgetc` function returns a `int`, so you must use an `int` variable to store its value.

Comment: Well in this case it is "should use" for `unsignef int` as `unsigned int` does work without any undefinedness or implementation-specified behaviour that would be markedly different from `int`